# Sometimes iOS Cordova application doesn't load script

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

It seems that sometimes the Cordova iOS app doesn't load the script at all. Checking the logs, I discovered that after

```
Resetting plugins due to page load.
```

it only prints

```
Finished load of file:../../www/index.html
```

without firing the `deviceready` event.

The same app on android works properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give a little more info? When does this occur? Is the resetting reproducable? Is the error reproducable?

Comment: no errors are printed. It happens casually. most of times happens when I run the application from Xcode.